# How do I fix the init rpy2 on Windows 8.1- Rblas missing?

Tags: rpy2

Is there a way to fix can't load R.dll and Rblas not found when try python -m rpy2.situation on windows 8.1 ?

Comment: Hi Bruno, welcome to SO! Can I suggest a little more info in your question to help get more attention? Maybe the error message you're seeing or a screenshot?